# What is the easiest way to get the value of a string field in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm using Drupal 8.5.4 and [Bootstrap Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_paragraphs). I have a custom module `foo` and a custom paragraph type `bar` defined within. In the template for `bar`, I use `kint` to inspect the content of the variable. It turns out it has 17 properties, and **none** of them are the value of the field. The first 14 of them are in core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field, [L#89-102](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.6.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FormatterBase.php#L89-L102). The last 3 are `0`, `#cache`, and `weight`.

Digging into the object, I found the field value in `content.bar.0['#context'].value`. Obviously using this method to access a simple field value is janky as hell, and I would prefer not to have to do this every time.

Two questions:

1. Is there a simpler way to access the field value? I don't mind using a twig filter if need be
2. Is there a way to configure my paragraph types to pass the context to the template, rather than all of the field data?

Comment: You could preprocess the paragraph entity for the variable

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to *paragraph--bar.html.twig*? Then this depends on what you want to do with the value.

Render the field value:

```
{{ content.field_example }}
```

Write code with it:

```
{% if paragraph.field_example.value == 'foo' %}
  <p>The field value is "foo".</p>
{% endif %}
```

See this blog post for *node.html.twig*, which applies here as well, only that the entity is `paragraph.` instead of `node.`: https://www.md-systems.ch/de/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig